# Theme paradigm in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, theming

Suppose you have an app written in Symfony2. How would go about creating a new theme bundle for this app without touching existing code?

It is very common to [override bundle templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) with files inside `/app/Resources/[Bundle]/views/*.twig`. But what if the theme needs to be a bundle?

For example for [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) you can either override twig files with files in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/*.twig` but if you want to override them in a bundle you need to make your *theme* bundle to be a child of FOSUserBundle, but that's not very convenient solution, because what if there are other bundles that have pages that needs to be themed?

Comment: Although that question seems similar, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. I'm asking how one can implement a theme that could be distributed as a bundle. FOSUserBundle is just an example of possible issues that one will face when trying to create such bundle.